# Rending HTML from a dataset field in SSRS

Tags: html, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've researched numerous websites and can't seem to figure out how to render HTML in my SSRS Report.
I right clicked on the textbox and chose placeholder properties with 'HTML - Interpret HTML tags as style' and that doesn't seem to work. When I previous of my report I still see the 
 tags and  tags etc...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it says "Interpret HTML tags as styles" what it should really say is...  "Interpret the following tags as HTML"

ie - only the following tags are interpreted in an RDL file

```
 - Hyperlinks: <A href>
 - Fonts: <FONT>
 - Header, style and block elements: <H{n}>, <DIV>, <SPAN>,<P>, <DIV>, <LI>, <HN>
 - Text format: <B>, <I>, <U>, <S>
 - List handling: <OL>, <UL>, <LI>
```

Having said that - even if HTML is not interpreted, it will ignore the tags, rather than displaying them as text (as your question show) - ***which leads me to think that your HTML is encoded?***  Can you post the HTML as it comes out of the database?

Couple of other things...
SSRS only has limited support for the style tags 
eg

```
SSRS will ignore RGB(66,66,66,) settings - you would need to use #666666
SSRS will ignore font-size in pixels - units needs to be in pts (eg 11pt)
SSRS will ignore line-height
```

But in your case, ssrs is ***not*** ignoring these tags/attributes, suggesting html encoding

Comment: I'm using a span tag and its not recognizing it. I can replace the <br> with a line break but its not recognizing the <span> tag

Comment: its actually not recognising any tags as HTML - if it was, it would simply ignore them (and not show them), rather than displaying them...